# getElementByID method not working in a Forloop with JSON object? any idea why

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, getelementbyid

Im trying to run the below code, trying to create new dIV for each object while iterating but for some reason this is not working. any one have any idea why?

```js
UserID = 2;

//window.onload = function() {


fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId= ' + UserID)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        var div2 = document.createElement("div");
        div1.style.border = "1px solid black";
        div1.style.margin = "20px";
        div1.style.padding = "10px";

        div2.style.border = "1px solid black";
        div2.style.margin = "20px";
        div2.style.padding = "10px";

        document.body.appendChild(div1);
        document.body.appendChild(div2);
        document.getElementById(div1).innerHTML = data[i].title;
        document.getElementById(div2).innerHTML = data[i].body;
      }

    }

  );
```

Comment: `.getElementById()` expects a **string**. You're passing it an element reference.

Comment: `div1` and `div2` must be a string. Does the console say any error message?

Comment: why not just set innerHTML with everything else?

Comment: Also you need to remove the space after the `=` here `userId= '+ UserID`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `innerHTML` before you append each `div`.

```js
UserID = 2;
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + UserID)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var div1 = document.createElement("div");
      var div2 = document.createElement("div");
      div1.style.border = "1px solid black";
      div1.style.margin = "20px";
      div1.style.padding = "10px";
      div1.innerHTML = data[i].title; // Assign the innerHTML here before appending

      div2.style.border = "1px solid black";
      div2.style.margin = "20px";
      div2.style.padding = "10px";
      div2.innerHTML = data[i].body; // Assign the innerHTML here before appending

      document.body.appendChild(div1);
      document.body.appendChild(div2);
    }
  });
```

Or you can assign an `id` and use that `id` (rather than the actual elements) with [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Parameters). From the docs:

> The ID of the element to locate. The ID is case-sensitive string which is unique within the document; only one element may have any given ID.

```js
UserID = 2;
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + UserID)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var div1 = document.createElement("div");
      var div2 = document.createElement("div");
      div1.style.border = "1px solid black";
      div1.style.margin = "20px";
      div1.style.padding = "10px";
      div1.id = data[i].id + "-title" // Assign a unique ID

      div2.style.border = "1px solid black";
      div2.style.margin = "20px";
      div2.style.padding = "10px";
      div2.id = data[i].id + "-body" // Assign a unique ID

      document.body.appendChild(div1);
      document.body.appendChild(div2);
      document.getElementById(data[i].id + "-title").innerHTML = data[i].title; // Find by the above unique ID
      document.getElementById(data[i].id + "-body").innerHTML = data[i].body; // Find by the above unique ID
    }
  })
```

Comment: @mplungjan yes because you updated it to have more than one data sample. If would recommend fixing since you've made the change.